# How do I get past cookies consent page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cookies

The link works fine in my browser, but when I access it with requests I instead get a page asking for cookie consent. I can't to find any link in here to the normal content. At the top of the page, there is a javascript script which I believe is what is asking for the cookies. This is it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="dtagent_ICA23jpqrx_7000100251007.js" 
  data-dtconfig="agentUri=dtagent_ICA23jpqrx_7000100251007.js|rid=RID_-169102772|rpid=-1264769392|domain=whirlpool.com|rt=10000|lastModification=1554899822221|lab=1|tp=500,50,0,1|reportUrl=dynaTraceMonitor|app=B2C"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js" 
  charset="UTF-8" 
  data-domain-script="fbd8c34f-e90b-43e9-9ab1-543aab83f925"></script>
```

What should I do to get past this?

Comment: You use a headless browser tool, like Puppeteer, and allow the script to run and modify the DOM. Then click the button, check the checkbox, or whatever. Of course, you're likely violating the site's terms of service by doing that with a script, but that's your problem.

Comment: write the script yourself... :)